# changing the index positioning in InputStream

Tags: java, android

I have a binary file which contains keys and after every key there is an image associated with it. I want to jump off different keys but could not find any method which changes the index positioning in input stream. I have seen the `mark()` method but it does not jump on different places.

Does anybody have any idea how to do that?

Comment: The operation you're looking for is usually called "seeking".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a [`long skip(long n)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#skip%28long%29) method that you may be able to use:

> Skips over and discards `n` bytes of data from this input stream. The `skip` method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over some smaller number of bytes, possibly `0`. This may result from any of a number of conditions; reaching end of file before `n` bytes have been skipped is only one possibility. The actual number of bytes skipped is returned. If `n` is negative, no bytes are skipped.

As documented, you're not guaranteed that `n` bytes will be skipped, so doublecheck the returned value always. Note that this does not allow you to "skip backward", but if it's [`markSupported()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#markSupported%28%29), you can [`reset()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset%28%29) first and *then* `skip` forward to an earlier position if you must.

---

#### Other options

You may also use [`java.io.RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), which as the name implies, permits random access with its [`seek(long pos)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) method.

You mentioned images, so if you are using [Java Advanced Imaging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Advanced_Imaging), another possible option is [`com.sun.media.jai.codec.FileSeekableStream`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/com/sun/media/jai/codec/FileSeekableStream.html), which is a [`SeekableStream`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/com/sun/media/jai/codec/SeekableStream.html) that takes its input from a `File` or `RandomAccessFile`. Note that this class is not a committed part of the JAI API. It may be removed or changed in future releases of JAI.

Comment: RandomAccessFile is probably the best option.  In JDK 7 another alternative might be java.nio.channels.FileChannel.

Comment: since the questions has 'android' tag - are you familiar with any JAI port for Android platform?