# AudioTrack Seek in Android

Tags: android

Can anyone help me how can I seek playing audio song to specific position like in mediaplayer , because my preference to play song using audiotrack not mediaplayer

Is there anyway to seek song to position using AudioTrack please let me know? Thanks
You can see my function of playing song using audiotrack it is working but I can't seek.

```
public void playDirect(){
    int i = 0;
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.output);
    int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    Log.v("bufferSize", " "+ bufferSize);
    audioTrack =  new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    byte[] music = new byte[512];

    try{
        audioTrack.play();
        audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(this);

        while((i = is.read(music)) != -1){
            audioTrack.write(music, 0, i);
            Log.v(" audioTrack ", " audioTrack = "+ (( audioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition( ) / audioTrack.getSampleRate( ) ) * 1000.0));
            //Log.v(" audioTrack ", " audioTrack = "+ audioTrack.setLoopPoints(500, 2000, 6));
        }

        audioTrack.stop();
        audioTrack.release();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't seek with AudioTrack, because you're just feeding samples to it, AudioTrack doesn't know anything about the file or the timing.

What you can do is seek the position in the InputStream file to the right position. Since you're audio is stereo, 16bits and 44100 hz, that means that each second of audio is

```
bytesPerSecond = 44100 * 2 * 2; // 44100 samples, 2 channels, 2 bytes per sample
```

So if you want to seek for example 5 seconds you would do this

```
seekPosition = 5 * bytesPerSecond;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply... can you tell how can I seek the position in the InputStream.?

Comment: It seems that InputStream is somewhat limited to seek operations. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474911/changing-the-index-positioning-in-inputstream) for some suggestions.

Comment: Btw, make sure that your seekPosition  is an odd number.